# Why can't baby Groot say more than his name

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2, groot

From what I heard. Flora Colossus's can only say a specific phrase when they get older because of their voice box hardening. If baby Groot is young enough to not have his voice box hardened, why does he still say the only phrase we all have heard?

Comment: I thought the explanation was that everything in their language just sounded like, "I am Groot!" to humans.

Comment: You're mixing media.

Comment: He is a pókemon

Answer (score 0):

how does any baby learn words.  Nobody is telling him to say DaDa or mommy.  He probably hears "Groot" every time someone talks to him. So he repeats the word he is most familiar with.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I invite you to take our [tour] to see what sort of answer we are looking for. This one, unfortunately, is more of a comment. If you have more to add, I recommend [editing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/177096/edit) it in.